# return javascript error via cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/find",
                    data: {coupon_name:value},
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert("success")
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError);

                    }
                });
```

What do I "echo" within my PHP page to throw an error?  Basically I'm using the ajax function to count the number returned, if <1 it needs to throw an error back to the JS.

Comment: You can take a look in here on "what to echo": http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html

Comment: Its worth noting that both answers so far (mine and @Amadan's) have mentioned that triggering `.error()` is probably the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery specification](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) defines `.error()` as:

> A function to be called if the request fails.

A failure HTTP code is one in the 400s or 500s, so a CakePHP equivalent of:

```
<?php
    http_response_code(500);
?>
```

should trigger it.

That said, I'm not sure that throwing an error is necessarily correct in your circumstances - your query hasn't actually errored, it just has returned zero results. So you may be best handling this within the `.success()` function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you leave the error for the real HTTP-related emergencies, and handle your code logic in your response. The easiest approach is making the response into JSON, returning an `error` component in the JSON if you encounter an error, and manually checking for its presence.

That said, you can use `$this->controller->response->statusCode(400)` (in CakePHP) or similar to send a status code that will trigger an error clause. But I recommend against it.